# installing pyGObject in pycharm has an error

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycharm, pygobject

while i'm trying to install pyGObject in my Pycharm. it does not work. and has an error :
[image]

and the output command :

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/1f/76533985b054473ef6ab1ba4d9c00d62da502f8b43d3171ae588ec81ae93/PyGObject-3.30.4.tar.gz
Collecting pycairo>=1.11.1 (from PyGObject)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/54/23d6cf3e8d8f1eb30e0e58f171b6f62b2ea75c024935492373639a1a08e4/pycairo-1.18.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycairo, PyGObject
  Running setup.py install for pycairo: started
    Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\Testt\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycairo\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tyl1chno\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\Testt\venv\include\site\python3.4\pycairo:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\cairo
    copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\cairo
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

    ----------------------------------------
```

my python version is  3.4.8 and working in windows 8.1

Comment: The problem is clearly mentioned: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required` . you will need to install the required windows software before you install the module.

Comment: I've found the link and added it to my answer below. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly mentioned: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required`.

You will **need to install the required windows software before you install the module.**

You can [download Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

**In case your system already has another installation**, you can find the workaround [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2014/07/17/installation-failing-with-a-newer-version-of-microsoft-visual-c-2010-redistributable-has-been-detected-on-this-machine/).

Comment: but I have Microsoft Visual C++ in my system. while I tried to download it from the link that u sent me ,it told me "A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.
"

Comment: That might be true. However, different software have specific dependencies. I have  about 14 different versions of `Microsoft visual C++` on my system (which I don't think should be the ideal scenario). Go ahead and install it anyway and then check if it works.

Comment: how can I install when it prevents me to continue installing ?

Comment: I installed that Visual C++ 10.0 from the link u sent me. but again have the previous error while I want to install pyGObject

Comment: Ok, I think I had the incorrect version for Visual C++ 10.

Looking at the error in more detail actually gave the correct link: `Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279` 

Please uninstall what you just installed and install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Sorry for not noticing earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187043/discussion-between-inaz-and-parvbanks).